# Create List in subsite from list template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have saved a list template in list template gallery from a subsite.
It is visible in list template gallery and i am to create list in root site but when i go another subsite i am not able to see that list template.
Can anyone give me reason why it is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a dumb-ass-question, but anyway: Are you sure it is a subsite and not another site collection? Also, is publishing features etc in the same state in both webs?

Comment: yup it is a subsite and publishing features are activated

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to enable the `Team Collaboration Lists` feature at the subsite level.

All the available list templates now appeared, including those saved in the list template gallery.